# What's the connection between the inverse function theorem and Newton's method?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, newton-raphson, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and consider the problem of solving $f(x) = y$.

The inverse function theorem says
$$ \mathrm{d} x= \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{f'(x)} $$

We could turn this ODE into a finite difference scheme:
$$x_{n+1} - x_{n} = \frac{\Delta y}{f'(x_n)}$$

where $\operatorname{sgn}(\Delta y)$ = $\operatorname{sgn}(y - y_n)$ in order to guide $y_n$ towards $y$.

If the stepsize is $|\Delta y| = 1$, we get Newton's method:
$$ x_{n+1} - x_n =  \frac{y - f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} $$

Is there more to this correspondence or is the above the extent of it?

Comment: Well, one is a theorem and one is a method. However, the inverse function theorem follows from the proof that Newton's method converges, and the proof is marginally stronger in that some 'closure' properties follow more easily.

Answer (score 1):

First, what does $dx=dy/f'(x)$ really mean? If you are treating differentials as finite differences, then this equation is really an approximation and rearranging it gives $dy/dx=f'(x)$.  But this just says the derivative is (approximately) the slope of the secant line...which isn't saying much (and is *not* the inverse function theorem).

This is the problem with using differential notation...it allows for such heuristic hand-waving.

Since you are really starting with a discrete approximation for the derivative, your heuristic manipulations wind up at Newton's method, since Newton's method  is essentially based on approximating a secant line (one that intersects the actual root of a function) with a tangent line.

In particular, given constant $y$, define $g(x):=y-f(x).$  We wish to find a root of $g$.  Pick some $x_n$ close enough to the root.  We hope $x_{n+1}$ will get us closer to the root.  To do so, we choose $x_{n+1}$ as the root of the *tangent line* to $g(x)$ at $x=x_n$:

$$g'(x_n)= \frac{g(x_n)-0}{x_n-x_{n+1}}\implies x_{n+1}-x_n=-\frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)}=\frac{y-f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)},$$

which is the Newton's method algorithm you obtained.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will update the question, to reflect on some of your points